# Partition of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, euclidean-geometry, big-list, riemannian-geometry

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be open. We want to find a *good* partition of $\Omega$ into more elementary sets.

In particular we want compact sets $K_j$'s and open sets $V_j$'s such that $K_j\subset V_j$ for each $j$ and \begin{equation}
\Omega=\cup K_j.
\end{equation}
Moreover, we may ask for more property like *each compact subset of $\Omega$ intersects only finitely many $V_j$'s*.

I have met such kind of construction many times, in real variable as well in Riemannian geometry, and there seem to be many ways to do such a partition. But now I guess it may help to have a collection of all possible ways to accomplish this, together with some special property of each partition.

I hope you guys can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Two relevant articles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_covering_lemma and http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/BoundedExhaustionFunction.html